# JQuery AJAX GET data from returned URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making a payment system. When a user pays and the payment is succeed then the URL returned is like:

```
success.php?ORDER_NUMBER=123456&TIMESTAMP=1426074386&PAID=DBE92B3F3C&METHOD=1&RETURN_AUTHCODE=1DAD7FA700AEAD89C181EA94A322954F
```

I have success.php file and have returned value in it. I am just wandering how to get those values in my div that is in another class.

```
<div id="third_nav" style="display: none"><h1>Receipt</h1></div>
```

My success.php class;

```
if ($module->confirmPayment($_GET["ORDER_NUMBER"], $_GET["TIMESTAMP"], $_GET["PAID"], $_GET["METHOD"], $_GET["RETURN_AUTHCODE"])) {
// Payment receipt is valid

$ORDER_NUMBER = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ORDER_NUMBER']);
$TIMESTAMP = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['TIMESTAMP']);
$PAID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['PAID']);


date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
$dateTime = date("d/m/Y", $TIMESTAMP);

echo $PAID;
echo "<br/>";

echo $dateTime;
echo "<br/>";
echo $ORDER_NUMBER; 

echo "<br/>";

//$_SESSION['cart'] = "";
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
 }else {
   echo "Payment failed";
 }
  ?>
```

The URL is sent from the bank after the successful payment. Thanks in advance. 
My jQuery AJAX;

```
function paymentSuccess(){

    event.preventDefault();
    $("#third_nav").html('');
    var values = //Don´t know what to be here
    $.ajax({
        url: "success.php",
        type: "get",
        data: values,
        success: function(html){
             alert("success");
             $("#third_nav").html(html);
              },
              error:function(){
              $("#third_nav").html('There is error while submit');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You can use session to store these value then get it where you want

Comment: @SheikhJames example would be appreciated sir!!

Comment: @BibashShah where is your ajax? post it too.

Comment: you can save data in php session like that when your success.php get hit.
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['ORDER_NUMBER'] = $_GET["ORDER_NUMBER"]; 
?>
After that you can access that data in other php file/class .

Comment: @Jai See my edited question. I do not know what will be the values.

Comment: @SheikhJames I do not want those data in other class. I just want that php file to be in another div.

Comment: Guys I am still stucked. Please suggest something. If there is another way to be done i will accept it as well. But need to solve this problem.